# Seeing commits of another branch

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request

I have access to repository on `git` but not "master" branch. I make another branch "paul_project" and when I am on this branch: I create another branch under it.

```
Admin@PAUL~/watirproject/AutomationProject (paul_project)
$ git checkout -b feature_one
```

which looks like this:

```
master
  paul_project
     feature_one
```

Similarly people like me, making another branches on top of "paul_project" as they also don't have access to "master". Which finally looks like this

```
master
  paul_project
     feature_one
     feature_two
     feature_three
```

Now problems is while raising `PR (Pull request)` we are seeing each other's commits too. And because of that, person who is going to review `PR` is having problem in reading commits, because on reading commits it looks like "feature_two" has more commits in it than it suppose to have, as it shows commits of "feature_one" also.

What is that we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `git rebase` after each `git pull` or `git fetch`/`git merge`.

It will allow git to rewind the history and, in case of conflicts, allow you to fix them. Your branch should be clean of duplicated commits after that.